# Count occurrences of values in dictionaries in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, key

Can somebody help me to solve this problem? Thank you in advance

```
import Foundation

func countOccurance(topics: [String : [String]], reviews: [String]) -> [String : Int] {
    
    var count: [String: Int] = [:]
    
    for (topicKeys, topicValues) in topics {
        for key in topicKeys {
            for val in topicValues {
                if reviews.contains(val) {
                   // count += 1
                    count["\(key)"]! += 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return count
}

let topics = [
    "price" : ["cheap", "expensive", "price"],
    "business" : ["small", "medium", "large"]
]
let reviews = "large company with expensive items. Some are very cheap"
let result = countOccurance(topics: topics, reviews: [reviews])

for (key,value) in result.enumerated() {
    print("\(key) : \(value)")
}
```

I want to return dictionary in below format.
Sample output
{
"price" : 2
"business" : 1
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible method of doing this, which should be slightly faster than excessive use of loops.

Method:

1. Split each review into its individual words.
2. Create a dictionary with the key being the review word and the value being the frequency.
3. Loop through every topic, then loop through every keyword in that topic.
4. If the keyword is in `reviewsDict`, get the number of occurrences and add it on to `count`'s occurrences.
5. Return dictionary result containing topics and their frequencies.

Solution:

```
func countOccurance(topics: [String: [String]], reviews: [String]) -> [String : Int] {
    var reviewsDict: [String: Int] = [:]
    for review in reviews {
        let reviewWords = review.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.letters.inverted)

        for word in reviewWords {
            guard !word.isEmpty else { continue }
            reviewsDict[word.lowercased(), default: 0] += 1
        }
    }

    var count: [String: Int] = [:]
    for (topic, topicKeywords) in topics {
        for topicKeyword in topicKeywords {
            guard let occurrences = reviewsDict[topicKeyword] else { continue }
            count[topic, default: 0] += occurrences
        }
    }

    return count
}
```

Result:

> ```
> 0 : (key: "price", value: 2)
> 1 : (key: "business", value: 1)
> ```

Comment: I just wrote a complimentary answer. Check it out, I think you might enjoy it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69473445/3141234

Comment: @Alexander That's a good answer in terms of readability, but I'd be a bit more concerned about the speed if there is lots of items because of the Big O of this. I tried to avoid as many `for`s/`map`s etc to try make this as fast as possible. I'm open to any performance improvements I could make.

Comment: It's actually all `O(total_reviews_length)`! The main missed optimization is that I hold (potentially large) arrays in memory of all the words. It could be improved by making smallers histograms on a per-review level, and then merging them in the end. However, that comes at the cost of processing time (of allocating lots of small dictionaries and merging them), so it's unclear which trade-off is better.

Comment: @Alexander I was thinking more the chains of `flatMap`-`filter`-`map`. I guess it doesn't make it take exponentially more time and so will make less of a difference, but I think that readability comes at the cost of iterating the array multiple times

Comment: Correct, though that doesn't impact Big-O performance. `2*O(n)` is still `O(n)`, just with a larger constant factor. Although optimizing it isn't so simple. CPU caches really complicate things, and can lead to counter-intuitive cases where multiple iterations over the same array actually turns out to be faster. There's also `lazy` which can help do it in one shot, but it introduces its own ARC and indirection-related overhead. In all, I guess I just valued the readability in this context.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `countOccurance(topics:reviews:)` function is violating the single responsibility principle (it's not really counting occurrences, it's also filtering words). As a result, it's very specialized to your one use-case, and you won't find any built-in facilities to help you.

On the other hand, if you broke down the problem into smaller, simpler, generic steps, you can leverage existing APIs. Here's how I would do this:

I don't know how familiar you are with the Sequence APIs, so I added some comments. Of course, you should remove these from your real code.

I've also added some intermediate variables. I think their names act as useful documentation (certainly better than using comments), but that's a matter of taste.

```
extension Sequence where Element: Hashable {
    typealias Histogram = [Element: Int]
    
    func histogram() -> Histogram { // I really with this was built-in :(
        reduce(into: [:]) { acc, word in acc[word, default: 0] += 1 }
    }
}

let topics = [
    "price" : ["cheap", "expensive", "price"],
    "business" : ["small", "medium", "large"]
]

// Invert the "topics" dictionary, to obtain a dictionary that can tell you what topic a keyword belongs to.
let topicsByKeyword = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues:
        topics.lazy.flatMap { topic, keywords in
            keywords.map { keyword in (key: keyword, value: topic) }
        }
    )

let reviews = ["large company with expensive items. Some are very cheap"]

let reviewWords = reviews
    .flatMap { $0.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.letters.inverted) } // Get a flat array of all words in all reviews
    .filter { !$0.isEmpty } // Filter out the empty words
    .map { $0.lowercased() } // Lowercase them all
    
let reviewTopicKeywords = reviewWords
    .compactMap { word in topicsByKeyword[word] } // Map words to the topics they represent

let reviewTopicKeywordCounts = reviewTopicKeywords.histogram() // Count the occurrences of the keywords, which is our final result.
```

Using a type might help organize some of these related behaviours:

```
import Foundation

extension Sequence where Element: Hashable {
    typealias Histogram = [Element: Int]
    
    func histogram() -> Histogram {
        reduce(into: [:]) { acc, word in acc[word, default: 0] += 1 }
    }
}

struct TopicKeywordCounter {
    let topicsByKeyword: [String: String]
    
    init(keywordsByTopic: [String: [String]]) {
        // Invert the "topics" dictionary, to obtain a dictionary that can tell you what topic a keyword belongs to.
        self.topicsByKeyword = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues:
            keywordsByTopic.lazy.flatMap { topic, keywords in
                keywords.map { keyword in (key: keyword, value: topic) }
            }
        )
    }
    
    public func countOccurances(in reivews: [String]) -> [String: Int] {
        let allReviewTopicKeywords = reivews.flatMap { review -> [String] in
            let reviewWords = allSanitzedWords(in: review)
            let reviewKeywords = mapWordsToTopics(from: reviewWords)
            return reviewKeywords
        }
        
        return allReviewTopicKeywords.histogram()
    }
    
    private func allSanitzedWords(in review: String) -> [String] {
        review
            .components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.letters.inverted)
            .filter { !$0.isEmpty }
            .map { $0.lowercased() }
    }
    
    private func mapWordsToTopics(from words: [String]) -> [String] {
        words.compactMap { topicsByKeyword[$0] }
    }
}

// Make your TopicKeywordCounter
let topicKeywordCounter = TopicKeywordCounter(keywordsByTopic: [
    "price" : ["cheap", "expensive", "price"],
    "business" : ["small", "medium", "large"]
])

let reviews = ["large company with expensive items. Some are very cheap"]

// ...then use it for any arrays of you reviews you want
let reviewTopicKeywordCounts = topicKeywordCounter.countOccurances(in: reviews)

print(reviewTopicKeywordCounts)
```

Let me know if you have any questions!